# Org-Wide email address adding extra characters and email relay send is being blocked

Tags: email, email-relay

We are trying to set up Email Relay in Sandbox, but when we send an email the system is adding a bunch of characters (and the emails are being blocked because of the funky FROM address).  Below is what the OWA is, vs what is being used as the FROM address when a message is delivered.

OWA: helpdesk@xxx.com
Delivered message FROM line: helpdesk=xxx.com__3g719kbf7o1jnb1e@3xksfaups1heg0jf.eqobum8o8oc40gws.w8vhy.59-4erkeai.cs172.bnc.sandbox.salesforce.com

Is it because we are sending the email from a Sandbox? Or is there a way to just have the OWA as the FROM address?

Comment: Have you created a sandbox and this OWA came from that parent Org, or OWA was configured in this sandbox only? If it came from parent Org, try resetting the OWA on this org afresh.

Comment: @BalwinderKumar this OWA came from our parent Org.  How do I reset the OWA? Just delete the address and add a new?

Comment: Yes deleting what came from Parent and adding the same directly in sandbox shall do.

Comment: I just deleted and re-added the email, but it is still coming over with a funky address... so I assume this is just because of the Sandbox.  IT dept. is looking for ways around this with our anti-virus software scanning the emails.  Appreciate the help @BalwinderKumar!

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue in my Sandbox and solved it by unchecking the 'Enforce email privacy settings' and 'Enable compliance with standard email security mechanisms' check-boxes. These check-boxes can be found in Email -> Deliverability in Setup.
[image]